# How do I remove this root folder link on my desktop?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

The folder is seen on the desktop screenshot here (***che's home*** folder symbol at the bottom).

It doesn't let me delete, move, rename, or anything...

I don't know what to do next.

I'm running 11.10 without unity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-visible false
```

Will remove the home icon from your desktop.

To re-enable it use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-visible true
```

Comment: No such schema 'org.gnome.nautilus.desktop'
this is what i got when typing the code in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 19.04 the following terminal command works as well:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
```